# How to transform list of tuples of dicts to a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas

#### Problem Statement

I have a list of tuples of dicts: [(A, B), (A, B),...]. I wrote `A` and `B` for the dictionaries because the keys are the same across these "types".

I want a dataframe with some keys from `A` and some keys from `B`.

Some of the keys in `A` are also present in `B`. I'd like to keep the keys from `A`.

#### Ways of approaching it:

I can think of a couple ways, and I'm curious which will be more performant. I've listed them in the order of my best guess as to performance:

- A list comprehension, building new dictionaries (or extending `A` with parts of `B`) and then `pd.DataFrame.from_records`.
- [`pd.DataFrame.from_records`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html) has an exclude parameter. Merge the larger dicts first and then exclude columns when building the dataframe.
- Transpose the list of tuples (maybe `zip(*)`?), create two dataframes with `.from_records`, one for each A and B, remove unnecessary columns from each, and then glue the resulting dataframes together side by side.
- Make each dict (row) a dataframe and then glue them on top of one another vertically (`append` or `concat` or something).

As a complete newbie to pandas, it seems to difficult to tell what each operation is, and when it's building a view or doing a copy, so I can't tell what is expensive and what isn't.

- Am I missing an approach to this?
- Are my solutions in the correct order of performance?
- If instead of dictionaries, `A` and `B` were dataframes, would concatenating them be faster? How much memory overhead does a dataframe have, and is it ever common practice to have a one-row dataframe?

#### Specifics:

Here's some simplified example data,

```
[({"chrom": "chr1", "gStart": 1000, "gEnd": 2000, "other": "drop this"}, 
  {"chrom": "chr1": "pStart": 1500, "pEnd": 2500, "drop": "this"}), 
 ({"chrom": "chr2", "gStart": 8000, "gEnd": 8500, "other": "unimportant"}, 
  {"chrom": "chr2": "pStart": 7500, "pEnd": 9500, "drop": "me"}) ]
```

The result I'd like I think would be the outcome of:

```
 pd.DataFrame.from_records([ 
  {"chrom": "chr1", "gStart": 1000, "gEnd": 2000, "pStart": 1500, "pEnd": 2500}, 
  {"chrom": "chr2", "gStart": 8000, "gEnd": 8500, "pStart": 7500, "pEnd": 9500}  ] )
```

#### Pseudocode of the solution I'd like:

I think this would work if dictionaries had a nice, in-place `select` method:

```
A_fields = [...]
B_fields = [...]
A_B_merged = [a.select(A_fields).extend(b.select(B_fields)) for a, b in A_B_not_merged]

A_B_dataframe = pd.DataFrame.from_records(A_B_merged)
```

Comment: Please read [how to make good reproducible pandas examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: How is the example data I've provided @MaxU ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using plain old dictionary merge that merges the start and end dictionary via pythonic (Python 3.5+) way and then uses `from_records` to construct `DataFrame`.

```
pd.DataFrame.from_records([{**d[0],**d[1]} for d in k])

  chrom  gEnd  gStart  pEnd  pStart
0  chr1  2000    1000  2500    1500
1  chr2  8500    8000  9500    7500
```

Comment: I really like this syntax, but how performant is it? And what do I do if I want to drop most of the columns from both `A` and `B` (or `d[0]` and `d[1]` in your solution)?

Comment: I ended up using this as the basis of my solution. =)

Comment: Care to break down how `**d[0]` works? is it a way of telling the dict expansion operator to only pick out the key (0th element) of each dict tuple?

Answer (score 1):

You need to go down two levels of your input to get it processed. Your best friend is then [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
import itertools as it
pd.DataFrame.from_records(it.chain.from_iterable(l))
Out[21]: 
  chrom    gEnd  gStart    pEnd  pStart
0  chr1  2000.0  1000.0     NaN     NaN
1  chr1     NaN     NaN  2500.0  1500.0
2  chr2  8500.0  8000.0     NaN     NaN
3  chr2     NaN     NaN  9500.0  7500.0
```

This requires classic and easy cleanup:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_records(it.chain.from_iterable(l)).set_index('chrom').stack().unstack()
Out[22]: 
         gEnd  gStart    pEnd  pStart
chrom                                
chr1   2000.0  1000.0  2500.0  1500.0
chr2   8500.0  8000.0  9500.0  7500.0
```

Comment: Hi @Boud, Thanks for your reply! 2 questions: What does pandas do when there are overlapping keys in `A` and `B`? And would you mind explaining a little more in your answer what `.set_index('chrom').stack().unstack()` is for?

Comment: Also, though my example data is oversimplified, there will be columns from `A` and columns from `B` which I'd like to drop. How should I be dropping them?

Comment: I'm concerned about `.set_index('chrom').stack().unstack()` since I have many rows which will have `chrom: 'chr1'`. I don't want to index by chrom. Nevertheless I like the `chain.from_iterable`... @Boud